# Load Rabbit or IBM mq config in Spring Boot based on en value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, ibm-mq

Use case : I want to load IBM or RabbitMq configuration based on a broker value (env variable). My listeners (Message Driven POJO) are working individually. This is required because my DeV and Test runs on Rabbit and QA and Prod Runs on IBM.

App: Spring Boot

I am thinking of loading the properties based on env.

Appconfig.java

```
@Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(classpath: application-${spring.profile.active}-{config-broker}.properties)

//Broker value can be IBM, Rabbit or None

public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory(){
..
}
```

Question: How do I make sure I load only IBM and Rabbit config and not load both.

Is there a way to load only one App config class and Message Listeners.

PS : with single config(ibm/rabbit), I am able to load and start my listener without any issues.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but I did want to point out that IBM offers a completely free IBM MQ Advanced for Developers download, maybe you could remove this difference in Dev by using that free version of MQ (assuming cost is the reason you do not use IBM MQ in Dev today).

Comment: What a terrible setup for functionality testing.  Do a JsohMc says, use IBM MQ Advanced for Developers for your DEV environment.

Comment: I know it's terrible and I also know I don't have much say in that.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have said, you should likely change your setup and use IBM MQ Advanced for development.

To answer your question, though, you could simply annotate your `@Beans` or whole `@Configuration` classes with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, like

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.profile.active", havingValue = "dev")
@Bean
// RabbitMQ...
```